# How to have sample dataset on AWS ElasticSearch or other service provider for SearchKitManager()?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, installation, aws-elasticsearch, searchkit

I am trying to use SearchKit and I want to know how to set up an ElasticSearch instance indexed with sample movie dataset.

Tried using:

1. AWS ElasticSearch Service. But don't have an actual dataset to upload through bulk API. The one that I have doesn't have indexing.

**Sample data:**

```
[  
   {  
      "movie_title":"Avatar ",
      "director_name":"James Cameron",
      "actor_1_name":"CCH Pounder",
      "actor_2_name":"Joel David Moore",
      "genres":"Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi",
      "language":"English",
      "country":"USA",
      "content_rating":"PG-13",
      "budget":"237000000",
      "title_year":"2009",
      "plot_keywords":"avatar|future|marine|native|paraplegic",
      "movie_imdb_link":"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499549/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1"
   },
   ...
]
```

2. Tried using appbase.io ready made movie-dataset. But I am not sure how to connect it with SearchKitManager().

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch) - it's an alternative to SearchKit from appbase.io (I work there) that's actively maintained. It supports direct use of appbase.io apps.

Re: SearchKitManager(), I am not sure if that may work as we don't support cluster level routes.